# Using PuLp and solving with Gurobi; how to see the solution after reaching Time Limit?

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, gurobi, pulp

I am using the PuLp module for formulating an MILP and I use Gurobi to solve the model. The model can get quite large and therefore I want to impose a Time Limit for solving. After experimenting with this, I cannot find the best solution that was found until Time Limit has reached, only the value of the objective function. The values of all variables are apparently all set to None. Is there any way I can see the actual solution when using PuLp and solving with Gurobi? If possible, I want to keep using PuLp.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [source code](https://github.com/coin-or/pulp/blob/master/pulp/apis/gurobi_api.py#L406) of the PuLP Gurobi API tries to read the solution file generated by the actual Gurobi command line call:

```
return_code = subprocess.call(cmd.split(), stdout=pipe, stderr=pipe) # This executes the Gurobi executable

        # Close the pipe now if we used it.
        if pipe is not None:
            pipe.close()

        if return_code != 0:
            raise PulpSolverError("PuLP: Error while trying to execute " + self.path)
        if not os.path.exists(tmpSol):
            # TODO: the status should be infeasible here, I think
            status = constants.LpStatusNotSolved
            values = reducedCosts = shadowPrices = slacks = None # This is likely where the `Nones` come from
        else:
            # TODO: the status should be infeasible here, I think
            status, values, reducedCosts, shadowPrices, slacks = self.readsol(tmpSol)
```

Later these values are set:

```
if status != constants.LpStatusInfeasible:
            lp.assignVarsVals(values)
            lp.assignVarsDj(reducedCosts)
            lp.assignConsPi(shadowPrices)
            lp.assignConsSlack(slacks)
```

As the comments indicate the status setting here isn't entirely obvious. The underlying problem seems to be that the Gurobi executable doesn't generate a solution file if it exceeds its timelimit.